# Leaflet vs Openlayers check color pixel of wms layer

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openlayers, wms

I have this in OpenLayers to check if the cursor is in a point of a wms layer.

```
map.on('pointermove', function (evt) {
              if (evt.dragging) {
                return;
              }
              const data = wmsLayer_test_csv_shp.getData(evt.pixel);
data[3].toString(16);
              //console.log(color);
              if(data && data[3] > 0){
                console.log("An item!");
```

This works perfectly and I would like to achieve the same in a leaflet map. The wms layer is the same as the layer in OpenLayers but I do not know how to make this in leaflet.

I'm trying to see in a log the layer and I can see the tiles that form the image, so I don't know if the solution is to get the tile where the cursor is and then somehow add the tile image to a canvas and check the color of the pixel there

```
DSG_mapa.map.on('mousemove', function (e) {
            var latlng = e.latlng;
            var point = DSG_mapa.map.latLngToContainerPoint(latlng, DSG_mapa.map.getZoom());
            var layerPoint = point.subtract(DSG_mapa.map.getPixelOrigin());
            var tileSize = 256;
            var tileCoords = L.point(Math.floor(layerPoint.x / tileSize), Math.floor(layerPoint.y / tileSize));
            var tileBounds = L.bounds(tileCoords.multiplyBy(tileSize), tileCoords.add([1, 1]).multiplyBy(tileSize));
            var tileUrl = WMS_LAYER.getTileUrl(tileCoords);
            if (imageData) {
                var pixel = imageData.data[((point.y * imageData.width) + point.x) * 4];
                console.log(pixel);
            }
        });
```

Could you please tell me how to do this in Leaflet? Is OpenLayers better than leaflet for my case and I have to change my project to OpenLayers?

it's just very simple to do this with OpenLayers and seems impossible to achieve it with Leaflet

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'getFeatureInfoUrl' method of the 'L.TileLayer.WMS' class to query the WMS layer at a specific location and retrieve information about the features at that location.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but I can't use that solution because the function is on a mousemove, so the numbre of requests will be so many that can saturate the server.

I would like to achive the same as OpenLayers do, that way the client side is who controls this.

What you mention is what I do to get data when clicking an element.

Comment: You can use a similar approach to OpenLayers by creating a canvas element and drawing the WMS layer on it. You can then use the canvas API to get the pixel color at the mouse position.